# 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability. - unable to start mongo on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to start mongodb on windows 32 bit system. I created \data\db in C: drive. Now when trying to run mongod command, gives me following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod.exe
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [main]
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [main]
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6200 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 32-bit host=PC265682
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.4
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: i386
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: i386
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
2016-03-28T15:14:55.942+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>
```

Comment: `Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1.,`

Comment: Right, But I don't understand this. What I need to do while starting the server or At the time of installation ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real error is `Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly` and the simplest solution is to follow the example.

e.g. `mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1`

For more information about MongoDB Storage Engines, see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage-engines/

Answer (score 7):

Most probably run `mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1` in mongodb_installation/bin and it will fix error.

If you get another error like: Detected unclean shutdown - mongod.lock is not empty, then try
 link [Recover a Standalone after an Unexpected Shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Run `mongod.exe --dbpath /data/db --repair`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**2017 ---**   **MongoDB Virsion 3.2.16**

I got solution With it and I think to hare Actual Issue with **`--journal`**

`mongod.exe --dbpath F:\data\db --journal  --storageEngine=mmapv1`

Source Link ... [Solution link](http://www.fatalerrors.org/a/main-32-bit-servers-don-t-have-journaling-enabled-by-default.html)   This website explain it perfectly.

My MongoDB Now working

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to follow the example:

```
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath "E:\mongodb\data"
```

Comment: This may or may not be an answer, but it certainly deserves more explanation than what has been provided. Please couch your solution by explaining what went wrong, and how it addresses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This command solved this issues:

```
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```